# Unmask and mask password characters using C#

Tags: c#, passwords, character, hide

I know that there is the exact same question that has been already answered, but when I tried to use the code given my compiler did not find the "Checked" function. I am a complete beginner in C# so can someone help me find what is wrong?

This is the code that I used :

```
private void checkBoxShowPassword_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        password_txt.PasswordChar = Show_Characters.Checked ? '\0' : '*';
    }
```

ERROR MESSAGE :

> Error 2   'System.Windows.Forms.CheckedListBox' does not contain a definition for 'Checked' and no extension method 'Checked' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Windows.Forms.CheckedListBox' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: And that is were the mistake was...I thought I could experiment with different check options...now that I used a CheckBox it's fixed!

Answer (score 0):

It's a property of a *checkbox control*. Depending on the technology you use, it may be called slightly differently. For WinForms you are after [CheckBox.Checked](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.checkbox.checked%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). Have a look at your login control, where you should have a checkbox.

In the code you posted the name of a checkbox control is `Show_Characters`, in your code it is probably called something else, so change `Show_Characters` to whatever you have in your code.